# Django-Cookiecutter cannot start the default project

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to start a fresh project with django-cookiectter, it builds fine but when i am trying to `docker-compose -f local.yml up` it gives me this error on django's service:

```
django_1    |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
django_1    |  * Restarting with stat
': No such file or directorycute 'python
dj_ekiosk_django_1 exited with code 127
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping dj_ekiosk_postgres_1 ... done
```

This is the local.yml file which i am trying to run (nothing changed its straight out of the cookiecutter project)

```
local.yml
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: dj_ekiosk_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: dj_ekiosk_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Comment: try with `sudo docker-compose -f local.yml up`

Comment: Using windows, same thing happens when I run it as administrator.

Comment: Providing the `local.yml`-file would probably help you in getting answers. As it is you're providing error logs and nothing else tangible. Creating a question that is [Minimal, Complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will increase your chances of getting an useful answer.

Comment: @ChristianW. The local.yml is straight out of the django-cookitecutter I haven't changed anything thats why I said 'fresh'. However I've put it for more convenience.

Comment: Did you create this cookiecutter project for Windows? It asks you if it is for windows when you create. You are developing on windows but running on linux container. Normally it is not a problem, but in this case this might be the reason for this error somehow. Do you have a line like `#!/usr/bin/python` in your manage.py, if so can you add this line here and do you have any import statement for windws like: `C:\user\...` ?

Comment: @fxgx Yes I did choose windows, I have the #! comment at the top of manage.py file as well. I have nothing else just the fresh project from the cookiecutter repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `\r\n`(CRLF) line endings in your manage.py, which is default for windows but causes error under Linux. The first line in your `manage.py` should be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python/r/n
```

you probably dont see `/r/n` part when you open the source code with a text editor/IDE but it is there. What you should do is convert CRLF line ending to LF line ending (which works for Linux). There are tools for doing that, and since you are developing on Windows, i would suggest configuring your IDE to use LF for line endings. (It is really easy to configure them with PyCharm, Visual Studio Code etc..)

Comment: Thank you! I've changed the Line Separator to Unix and OSX (\n) (LF) in pycharm in the global settings and everything worked out!